# Spatio-temopral wavelet analysis

Tags: matlab, geospatial, wavelet

Am quite new to wavelet analysis as well as stackoverflow and would wold like some help. I am performing a spatio-temporal analysis of rainfall data. 
With PCA, I can reduce the dimension of the rainfall data into a few leading modes, yielding EOFs (which explain spatial variability)
and principal components (explaining temporal variability).

I would like to perform a similar analysis with wavelets using Matlab Wavelet Toolbox. As of now, I am able to decompose a 2D data (spatial decomposition) 
but unable to take into account the temporal variability in the data.

My first course of action has been to first compress the data with PCA and then perform wavelet decomposition of the leading modes in both the 
spatial (EOFs) and temporal (PCs) domain.

I am wondering if this is the right way to perform such an analysis and would like suggestions as to how to proceed.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You might get (better) answers to this at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or even at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, will post the question on the suggested fora whiles I still welcome answers offered on this platform.